# Date Formatter выдает правильную дату с неправильной строки

Tags: ios, swift, дата, datetime, simpledateformat

Почему dateFormatter выдает правильную дату из строки неправильного формата? (3 строка)
Но вот строку уже с даты уже выдает верную. (4 строка)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/////07////////10") //"Jul 10, 2020 at 12:00 AM"

dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // "2020-01-24"
```

Comment: Тут ответ почему:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897815/5523526 Тут ответ как:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841330/5523526

Answer (score 2):

У Вас опечатка в строке (здесь неправильно понял вопрос)

```
dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) // "2020-01-24"
```

`Date()` - ваше текущее время.

Замените на `date` полученную ранее:

```
dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

---

А по поводу парсинга такой строки, насколько знаю, `-` подразумевает под собой любой разделитель. Ну или "не баг, а фича"

Answer (score 0):

Я поэкспериментировал с `dateFormat` и строкой `2020/////07////////10`, и получается, что он парсит такую строку только при формате `yyyy-MM-dd`. Скажем, если задать любой другой формат (например `yyyy_MM_dd`, `dd-MM-yyyy`), то парсинг не увенчается успехом и вернется `nil`.

Точно так же если мы в строке `2020/////07////////10` заменим слеши на другие знаки-разделители, скажем дефис или подчеркивание, то парсинг тоже не удастся. Видимо это встроенный вариант парсинга по умолчанию, когда дата приводится к виду `2020/07/10`

**Дополнение**

Эта строка также парсится с форматом `yyyy.MM.dd` или `yyyy,MM,dd`

Comment: Проверьте 2020...10...07 или 2020,,,10,,,07 ;)

Comment: @VAndrJ да верно с этими вариантами тоже работает. Значит не работает с нестандартными разделителями

Answer (score 0):

Из документации: When working with **fixed** format dates, you set the dateFormat property to specify a format string.

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

И тогда let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/////07////////10") будет nil

Comment: Даже без добавления времени не все форматы даты будут парситься, например даже `yyyy/MM/dd` не сработает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897815/5523526
Здесь ответ

Comment: Спасибо, но по ссылке все-таки не ответ, а предположение )